# How to add a command option like a tkinter Button in this custome widget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, widget, tk-toolkit

I have tried to create a custom widget name `OnOffButton` but now i want to call a function when the widget is clicked like `Button` widget.

I want command option in my widget like `tkinter.Button` has.

Help would be really appreciated.

I am a beginner, so please forgive me if the code logic or the code formation is not good.

```
import tkinter as tk

class OnOffButton(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent,barwidth=3,default='OFF',font='consolas 12 bold'):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ON = "ON "
        self.OFF = 'OFF'
        self.space = ' '*barwidth
        self.font = font
        self.on_variable = tk.IntVar(self,value=0)
        self.off_variable = tk.IntVar(self,value=0)
        self.state = 0

        self.on_btn = tk.Checkbutton(self, text=self.space, indicatoron=False, font=self.font,fg='green',\
            onvalue=1, offvalue=0, variable=self.on_variable, command=self.click_on)
        self.off_btn = tk.Checkbutton(self, text=self.OFF, indicatoron=False, font=self.font,fg='red',\
            onvalue=1, offvalue=0, variable=self.off_variable, command=self.click_off)

        self.on_btn.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.off_btn.grid(row=0, column=1)
        if default.lower() == 'off':
            self.off_btn.select()
            self.on_btn.deselect()

        else:
            self.on_btn.select() 
            self.off_btn.deselect()
            self.on_btn['text'] = self.ON
            self.off_btn['text'] = self.space
        
    def click_on(self):
        if self.on_variable.get() == 0:
            self.off_btn.select()
            self.off_btn['text'] = self.OFF
            self.on_btn['text'] = self.space
            self.state = False
        
        elif self.on_variable.get() == 1:
            self.off_btn.deselect()
            self.off_btn['text'] = self.space
            self.on_btn['text'] = self.ON
            self.state = True
    
    def click_off(self):
        if self.off_variable.get() == 0:
            self.on_btn.select()
            self.on_btn['text'] = self.ON
            self.off_btn['text'] = self.space
            self.state = True
        
        elif self.off_variable.get() == 1:
            self.on_btn.deselect()
            self.on_btn['text'] = self.space
            self.off_btn['text'] = self.OFF
            self.state = False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('200x200')

    btn = OnOffButton(root)
    btn.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a `command` option in the `__init__()` function and call the passed callback inside `click_on()` and `click_off()` function:

```py
from inspect import isfunction

class OnOffButton(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, ..., command=None): # added command option
        ...
        self.command = command if isfunction(command) else None
        ...

    def click_on(self):
        ...
        if self.command:
            self.command()

    def click_off(self):
        ...
        if self.command:
            self.command()

...

btn = OnOffButton(root, command=lambda: print("clicked"))
...
```

Comment: i tried but nothing happed, i passed a function which prints clicked but it is not printing

Comment: It works fine for me. Can you update your question with the changes.